How to implement infinite scroll with particle system?
I have been trying to implement infinite scroll with my particle system, but have not been successful. Basically on my site the particle system is the background, and I have fixed content on top. But I would like to infinitely scroll through the background, generate new particles as I go, and then seamlessly transition when I am at the top again. I am utilizing webflow, so that is where I manage the CSS.
I am quite new to this, so I apologize if my query seems a bit naive.
Does anyone know how to best approach this?
Thank you,
Sina
Here is the particles.js code I am using (used this resource):
<style>
.particles-js-canvas-el {
position: absolute;
max-width: 100%;
max-height:100%;
left: 0%;
top: 0%;
right: 0%;
bottom: 0%;
z-index: 0;
}</style>

<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/particles.js/2.0.0/particles.min.js"></script> 

<script>

particlesJS(

{
  "particles": {
    "number": {
      "value": 11,
      "density": {
        "enable": true,
        "value_area": 800
      }
    },
    "color": {
      "value": "#000000"
    },
    "shape": {
      "type": "edge",
      "stroke": {
        "width": 0,
        "color": "#000000"
      },
      "polygon": {
        "nb_sides": 5
      },
      "image": {
        "src": "img/github.svg",
        "width": 100,
        "height": 100
      }
    },
    "opacity": {
      "value": 1,
      "random": false,
      "anim": {
        "enable": false,
        "speed": 1,
        "opacity_min": 0.1,
        "sync": false
      }
    },
    "size": {
      "value": 8,
      "random": false,
      "anim": {
        "enable": false,
        "speed": 40,
        "size_min": 0.1,
        "sync": false
      }
    },
    "line_linked": {
      "enable": false,
      "distance": 150,
      "color": "#ffffff",
      "opacity": 0.4,
      "width": 1
    },
    "move": {
      "enable": true,
      "speed": 3,
      "direction": "none",
      "random": false,
      "straight": false,
      "out_mode": "out",
      "bounce": false,
      "attract": {
        "enable": false,
        "rotateX": 600,
        "rotateY": 1200
      }
    }
  },
  "interactivity": {
    "detect_on": "canvas",
    "events": {
      "onhover": {
        "enable": true,
        "mode": "repulse"
      },
      "onclick": {
        "enable": false,
        "mode": "repulse"
      },
      "resize": true
    },
    "modes": {
      "grab": {
        "distance": 400,
        "line_linked": {
          "opacity": 1
        }
      },
      "bubble": {
        "distance": 400,
        "size": 40,
        "duration": 2,
        "opacity": 8,
        "speed": 3
      },
      "repulse": {
        "distance": 200,
        "duration": 0.4
      },
      "push": {
        "particles_nb": 4
      },
      "remove": {
        "particles_nb": 2
      }
    }
  },
  "retina_detect": true
}

For the infinite scroll, I have tried adding variations of this:
    const particlesCanvas = document.getElementById('particles-js');
    let scrollTop = 0;

    function infiniteScroll() {
      const scrollPosition = window.scrollY;
      const windowHeight = window.innerHeight;

      particlesCanvas.style.transform = `translateY(${-scrollPosition}px)`;

      if (scrollPosition >= windowHeight) {
        window.scrollTo(0, 1);
      }

      requestAnimationFrame(infiniteScroll);
    }

    window.addEventListener('scroll', infiniteScroll);
    requestAnimationFrame(infiniteScroll);
  });

The best I can manage is infinite scroll (200% canvas height), but then it being jumpy and the background being completely generated anew.
